# JS: Convert a specific values from an object into an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
var obj = 
[
 {
   "value": "aep",
   "label": "AEP"
 },
 {
   "value": "cap",
   "label": "CAP"
 },
 {
   "value": "casl",
   "label": "CASL"
 } ]
```

And I want to convert the values of the labels ONLY into an array so that the end result is:

```
["AEP", "CAP", "CASL"]
```

How do I only get the label values converted in an array?

Comment: Hint #1: Try a loop (`for`) - where you would iterate over this array and `.push()` into another result array.

Comment: @community: please let them solve this problem themselves, don't post the complete code. Thank you.

Comment: That isn't an object... it contains objects.

Answer (score 1):

First: `obj` is not an object, it is an array since the parent brackets are `[]` and not `{}`. I will, however, keep the name the same. This might have caused you some confusion, e.g.

```
var object = {};
var array = [];
var arrayOfObjects = [{},{},{}];
var objectOfArrays = {array1: [],array2: [],array3: []};
```

To loop an array you can use a for loop:

```
// new array
var newArray = [];
// iterates over each index in the array
for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
    // Access the specific index, then access its `label` property
    // Push into `newArray`
    newArray.push(obj[i].label);
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/theblindprophet/pen/RRxVba

Comment: The `objectOfArrays` declaration is invalid syntax; although I appreciate the heuristic you are making a point specifically about syntax. It is also confusing that `obj` in the working code section does not refer to `obj` in the preceding section, but to `obj` in the OP's question.

Comment: My apologies, I see what I did, better?

Comment: Use map is the easiest solution:
obj.map(function(inner) { return inner.label });

Answer (score 0):

**This is a functional solution and not the most straightforward one**, you may want to refer to @theblindprophet's answer for the imperative approach to this problem.

Pretty easy task to be done in a functional way:

```
var labels = obj.map(function(inner) { return inner.label });
```

How does one approach such a problem: You need to think of how to transform the data you have to the data you want. In this case you have an Array of Objects and you want to transform this Array of Objects to an Array of Strings placed inside that Object.

The above code iterates over the Array and returns the value you want for the current element of the Array, building a new Array in the course (`map`)

Comment: Someone cannot implement a simple loop and you suggest a hof-based solution. Do you honestly think it teaches them anything?

Comment: @zerkms Yes, it teaches them about the `Array.prototype.map` method. Why don't you teach us something and explain what HOF stands for?

Comment: Disclaimer: I added the explanation afterwards.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function --- that's essentials for writing code "in a functional way".

Comment: "Yes, it teaches them about the Array.prototype.map method" --- well, I don't think so: `Array.prototype.map` and the whole "functional" thing is incomparably more complicated than a simple loop. You learn iteratively from simple to complicated. But whatever.

Comment: Nah, not whatever. You're right @zerkms, i read your comment on the initial question right after hitting the send button and felt guilty immediately.

Comment: @zerkms this is true, but also weird.. This is not a teaching community, we help to solve problems

Comment: Just for the record, it's not me that downvoted :-) I don't think any of answers is particularly helpful for OP to grow but I definitely would not punish.

Comment: @webdeb it depends on what "help to solve problems" means: if it means "write code for free" - then it's one thing. If it is: "learn think wide so that you can solve problems in general" - it's another thing. The OP's current problem is that they cannot interpolate their current knowledge to apply it for an abstract task. And teaching them thinking of "code templates" is barely helpful. <-- Just my personal thoughts and teaching experience.

Comment: I added a pointer to the more straightforward solution. I do agree with @zerkms that we should nudge people in the right directions, especially if questions are this simple.

Comment: @zerkms well good point, but then the best would be to answer with a link to www.google.com?q=for+loop+javascript or just like you did: #Hint for loop

Comment: @webdeb well, not particularly. But probably a sketchy non-js code, with accompanying explanation, and probably with some extras with "if you want to filter" and "if you want some transformations applied to data".

Comment: @zerkms You seem very opinionated about what a good answer would look like. Why don't you write one, and we can continue this discussion in *its* comment thread.

Comment: @this-vidor I don't know what would be a good answer for this very question.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop

```
 var out = [];
 for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
     out.push(obj[i].label);
 }
 console.log(out);
```

Comment: Why `len = obj.length; i < len` and not `i < obj.length`?

Comment: @theblindprophet in 2016 people still believe it makes any difference.

Comment: Your comment is quite vague (hinting sarcasm). I would like to know if that is more efficient.

Comment: @zerkms It does if you have the ungodly position of writing for IE 8 <. theblindprophet: It was faster in older browsers. Each time the loop condition was checked, the engine would manually retrieve the length again which required a scope traversal.

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, meant to say property traversal. It had to check the list of properties on the object, verify that `length` exists, and grab it's value from wherever it was in memory.

Comment: Yes, this is a technique targeted at the older browsers. But is this going to hamper the performance in a negative way?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple.  You can use map function of javascript array

```
var obj = 
[
 {
   "value": "aep",
   "label": "AEP"
 },
 {
   "value": "cap",
   "label": "CAP"
 },
 {
   "value": "casl",
   "label": "CASL"
 } ] 

var arr = obj.map(function(data){return data.value});
```

Comment: You mean `return data.label`.